# Рандом переменной JS в заданном интервале. Почему не работает?

Tags: javascript

Есть код, который задаёт смену картинок:

```
var image_count = 7;
var interval = 16000;
var time_out = 5;

var i = 0;

var timeout;
var opacity = 100;

function change_image() {
    opacity--;
    var j = i + 1;
    var current_image = 'img_' + i;
    if (i == image_count) j = 1;
    var next_image = 'img_' + j;
    document.getElementById(current_image).style.opacity = opacity / 100;
    document.getElementById(current_image).style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + opacity + ')';
    document.getElementById(next_image).style.opacity = (100 - opacity) / 100;
    document.getElementById(next_image).style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + (100 - opacity) + ')';
    timeout = setTimeout('change_image()', time_out);
    if (opacity == 1) {
        opacity = 100;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
}

setInterval(function () {
    i++;
    if (i > image_count) i = 1;
    change_image();
}, interval);
```

Вместо строчки:

```
var i = 0;
```

Я добавил:

```
var i = Math.random();

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Но почему-то не работает. То есть когда переменная `i` равна нулю, то он берёт первую картинку в списке и далее меняет подряд. А я хотел, чтобы он брал рандомную картинку и далее шёл по порядку в списке. Вот список картинок:

```
<img src="/images/fon/70.jpg" id="img_1" style="position: absolute;">
<img src="/images/fon/50.jpg" id="img_2" style="opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0);  position: absolute;">
<img src="/images/fon/49.jpg" id="img_3" style="opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0);  position: absolute;">
<img src="/images/fon/55.jpg" id="img_4" style="opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0);  position: absolute;">
<img src="/images/fon/56.jpg" id="img_5" style="opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0);  position: absolute;">
<img src="/images/fon/77.jpg" id="img_6" style="opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0);  position: absolute;">
<img src="/images/fon/88.jpg" id="img_7" style="opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0);  position: absolute;">
```

Comment: почему ты присваиваешь `Math.random()` а не `getRandomInt(0, 7)`?

Comment: @user250973 То есть рандомное число не берется в границе от 0-7 да?

Comment: потому что так было сказано в справочнике: http://javascript.ru/math.random

Comment: не знаю.. в итоге картинки перестали меняться вообще.. так что, думаю не работает в принципе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var i = getRandomInt(0, 7);

function getRandomInt(min, max) { 
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Comment: зачем `+ 1`? *(2 символа нужно...)*

Comment: По этой логике числа разве будут в диапазоне ?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan да, будут - http://jsbin.com/jiqocamuri/edit?js,console

Comment: @ZoltanToth   да, но другой компактнее.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan согласен.. я просто взял исходный код автора и указал как его нужно использовать, чтоб работало

Answer (score 1):

Для того что бы взять рандомное число в выбранном диапазоне надо сделать так:

```
Math.random()*(b-a)+a
```

У вас `a=0`, `b=7`;

То есть вы должны сделать так:

```
var i = Math.random()*7;
```

А так у вас будут целые числа в заданном диапазоне вами:

```
Math.floor((Math.random() * 7));
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: math is not defined

Comment: Исправлено должно было быть с заглавной буквы.

Comment: Ага. А зачем было правку @Дмитрий откатывать. которая это исправляла?

Comment: @Qwertiy потому что там не только это было исправлено, многое другое то же